# How to Run script for multiple text files with a common string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, file-io, glob

In my research work I have multiple text files has a common string "Max", and Max has different values in range of 0.10 to 2.00 with step 0.10 as follow:

```
 A_100Hz_Rate20Hz_5tot_0.10Max_1_ 
 A_100Hz_Rate20Hz_5tot_0.10Max_2_
 A_100Hz_Rate20Hz_5tot_0.10Max_3_
 .
 .
 .
 A_100Hz_Rate20Hz_5tot_2.00Max_1_ 
 A_100Hz_Rate20Hz_5tot_2.00Max_2_
 A_100Hz_Rate20Hz_5tot_2.00Max_3_
```

I need to import all files depending on the value of Max (ex: 0.10Max) to get the average of files with the same Max values separately to get:

```
 Ave_A_100Hz_Rate20Hz_5tot_0.10Max_3_
 .
 .
 .
 Ave_A_100Hz_Rate20Hz_5tot_2.00Max_3_
```

I’ve tried a manual glob module, and it's working good for one value of "Max" but for the full range it doeson't work. This is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import glob
import pandas as pd

h = np.linspace(0.10,2.00,20)  
for x in h: 
     x1 = ("%.2f" % x)
     glob_path = 'input/*_{}Vbr_*.txt'.format(x1)
     import_files = glob.glob(glob_path)
     print(x,import_files )
     for index, file_name in enumerate(import_files ):
          merged_data = pd.read_csv(file_name, header=None, delimiter="\t").values
          if index==0:    
               summation = merged_data
          else:
               summation = summation + merged_data
          averaging = summation/len(import_files)         
          np.savetxt('output/Ave_'+file_name[10:], averaging, delimiter="\t" )
```

I need to write a general script. But, in my case now I used the script with just two values x = 1.50 and x = 2.0 to make it simple. I tried print(import_files) and expected the output to be:

```
['input\\A_100Hz_Rate20Hz_5tot_1.50Max_1_.txt', 
'input\\A_100Hz_Rate20Hz_5tot_1.50Max_2_.txt', 
'input\\A_100Hz_Rate20Hz_5tot_1.50Max_3_.txt']


['input\\A_100Hz_Rate20Hz_5tot_2.00Max_1_.txt', 
'input\\A_100Hz_Rate20Hz_5tot_2.00Max_2_.txt', 
'input\\A_100Hz_Rate20Hz_5tot_2.00Max_3_.txt']
```

But the actual output is (in short):

```
0.1 []
0.2 []
1.5 ['input\\A_100Hz_Rate20Hz_5tot_1.50Max_1_.txt', 
'input\\A_100Hz_Rate20Hz_5tot_1.50Max_2_.txt', 
'input\\A_100Hz_Rate20Hz_5tot_1.50Max_3_.txt']
1.6 []
1.7 []
2.0['input\\A_100Hz_Rate20Hz_5tot_2.00Max_1_.txt', 
'input\\A_100Hz_Rate20Hz_5tot_2.00Max_2_.txt', 
'input\\A_100Hz_Rate20Hz_5tot_2.00Max_3_.txt']
```

and it caused an error in the kernel

```
      np.savetxt('output/Ave_'+file_name[10:], averaging, delimiter="\t" )

 NameError: name 'file_name' is not defined
```

Please, Any suggestions?

Comment: As far as the actual output is concerned, you will get empty list ([ ]) for cases where there is no match with glob pattern. 
For NameError: name 'file_name' is not defined, I am guessing it is some indentation issue with respect to inner for loop.  How did the code go pass "pd.read_csv(file_name..." line which also uses same variable (file_name)

Comment: Just to elaborate on ranjith's comment, you should replace the `print(import_files )` with `print(x, import_files)` to make more evident for which `x` value you get empty lists.

Comment: @ranjith the code is working good without my manual glob for the full range 

       h = np.linspace(0.10,2.00,20)  
       for x in h: 
            x1 = ("%.2f" % x)
            glob_path = 'input/*_{}Vbr_*.txt'.format(x1)

Comment: @SergeBallesta - print(x, import_files) gives me: 0.1 [ ] , 0.2 [ ] and so on...

Comment: @SergeBallesta - I edited my question, look at it please!

Comment: @H.H: Do you *really* have a file name containing 0.1 when x is 1.5???

Comment: @SergeBallesta - sometimes I have all range from 0.1 to 2.0 and sometimes no. In my case now I have just x = 1.5 and x = 2.0, but I need to write a general scripts for all cases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you have just to test whether `import_file` is empty:

```
for x in h: 
     x1 = ("%.2f" % x)
     glob_path = 'input/*_{}Vbr_*.txt'.format(x1)
     import_files = glob.glob(glob_path)
     print(x,import_files )
     if len(import_files) != 0:
         for index, file_name in enumerate(import_files ):
              merged_data = pd.read_csv(file_name, header=None, delimiter="\t").values
              if index==0:    
                   summation = merged_data
              else:
                   summation = summation + merged_data
          averaging = summation/len(import_files)         
          np.savetxt('output/Ave_'+file_name[10:], averaging, delimiter="\t" )
```

Comment: it gave me error

     if (len(import_files != 0):
                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax